# how to ensure that remote peer receive all data before call asio socket close() function

Tags: c++, boost-asio, send, shutdown

the problem is when I call asio socket function close() to close socket,
 the data sent before were all lost！

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that all of the data is *written* before `close` is called, you should make use of io_service's event loop.

Take a look at asio's [chat client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp) as an example of how to do it:

```
void write(const chat_message& msg)
{
  io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_write, this, msg));
}

void close()
{
  io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_close, this));
}
```

By `post`ing the actual write to the event loop, you're delegating the work of making sure everything happens in the correct order.

If you want to make sure the remote endpoint has received everything before you close the socket, you'll need to build in some kind of protocol, i.e. having the remote endpoint send a message confirming as much.